# 2008 bmw 750li e65 torque specification

Tags: bmw, torque-specification

torque specification front and rear, 18mm caliper bolts ? I will be replacing the brake pads and rotors on my 2008 bmw 750li e65 , bmw repair manuals (bentley publishers) do not have a publication for my e65 model .

Answer (score 1):

110 Nm is the proper torque for the caliper the steering knuckle bolts.

[image]